# Draw the discontinuity symbol with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Is there an easy way to draw the discontinuity symbol with tikz?

It is the symbol shown at the y axis in the following picture (taken from the pgfplots documentation.

I can always draw it manually but it is not always easy especially if the line has an angle. I tried to do it with a style, but I couldn't figure it out.

Optimally I would like to just specify the start and the end point of a line segment and the sign should be drawn in the center.

[image: my picture]

### Update

Jake solution is nice, but it doesn't work nicely with filling. Is there a way to draw the symbol while filling continues to work?

Leo Liu's answer works with filling but you have to tweak the parameters each time you use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `decorations`  library and declares a new `discontinuity` decoration, which is essentially a single `zigzag` in the middle of the first segment of a path. The length and amplitude of the discontinuity symbol are controlled using the standard decoration options `segment length` and `amplitude`.

[image: Discontinuity symbol]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{discontinuity}{start}{
  \state{start}[width=0.5\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=up from center]
  {}
  \state{up from center}[width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength, next state=big down]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{big down}[next state=center finish]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{center finish}[width=0.5\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance, next state=do nothing]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}
  }
  \state{do nothing}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=do nothing]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=yellow,decoration={discontinuity,amplitude=1ex},decorate](0,0) -- (3,2)  --  (5,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now that I've delved deeper in tikz, I 've started to understand what you did here. It is great! thank you!

Answer (score 17):

`pgfplots` has discontinuities decoration on the axis. See '4.8.11 Axis Discontinuities' in the manual.

Example in the manual:

```
% \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=center,
tick align=outside,
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
ymin=95, enlargelimits=false
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-4:4,samples=20]
{x*x+x+104};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

It is implemented using zigzag decorations. Then you can draw it your self, for example (it is not a good implementation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{discont/.style={decoration={zigzag,segment length=12pt, amplitude=4pt},decorate}}
\def\discontarrow(#1)(#2)(#3)(#4);{
  \draw[discont] (#2) -- (#3);
  \draw[->] (#1) -- (#2) (#3) -- (#4);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\discontarrow(0,0)(1,0)(1.5,0)(4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2)
  \pszigzag[coilarm=1.5cm](0,0)(4,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]