# TikZ: Draw interrupted line with text and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/tikz-how-to-draw-an-interrupted-line) question I try to draw an interrupted line, but with text below / above and arrows at both ends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{discontinuity}{start}{
  \state{start}[width=0.5\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=first wave]{}
  \state{first wave}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength, next state=second wave]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{-0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{0.75\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{-0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{-0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{-0.75\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
\state{second wave}[width=0pt, next state=do nothing]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{-0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{0.75\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{-0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{-0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{0.25*\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength}{-0.75\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        {\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
}
  \state{do nothing}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=do nothing]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[](S0){\LaTeX};
\node[above right = 26mm and 18mm of S0](S1){\LaTeX};

\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
\draw[decoration={discontinuity,amplitude=0.5cm,segment length=0.25cm,meta-segment length=0.5cm},decorate,<->,dotted,ultra thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={discontinuity,amplitude=0.5cm,segment length=0.25cm,meta-segment length=0.5cm,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift|TEXTTEXT}}}](S0) -- (S1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

As we can see, the text is not readable and the arrows at the end of the lines are also missing.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example doesn't work at all. We don't have the image you've used of course, and the `positioning` library is needed, but even after using `example-image` instead, and adding the library, the code produces an error.

Comment: Why use an image rather than `\LaTeX`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT I edited my question with your suggestions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} %
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                babel,                     % <--- 
                decorations.markings,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 22mm,
            > = Straight Barb,
   decoration = {markings,
                 mark=at position 0.5 with {
                        \draw[line width=1.6pt, -] 
                            (0pt,4pt) .. controls + (2pt,-2pt) and + (-2pt,2pt) .. (0pt,-4pt);
                        \draw[white, line width=1pt, solid, -]
                            (0pt,4.1pt) .. controls + (2pt,-2pt) and + (-2pt,2pt) .. (0pt,-4.1pt);
                                            }
                 },
every edge quotes/.append style = {inner ysep=5pt}
                    ]
      \node (n1) {\LaTeX};
      \node (n2) [above right=of n1] {\LaTeX};
      \path (n1) to ["TEXT",sloped] (n2);
      \draw[dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 0.5pt, <->, postaction={decorate}]
            (n1) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The result looks great! But I got an error in this line `\path (n1) to ["TEXT",sloped] (n2);` **Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.** If I comment out this part of code I got the interrupted line without any text.

Comment: @Passe `Zarko`'s suggestion works without any error, hopefully you need to update your `setup`

Comment: @Passe, I use recent of the `tikz` package, i.e. version 3.1.4 but it should works with versions after 3.0.1. However, if you use `babel` package (for example with `french` option) in your document, than may help if you add to `tikz` libraries a library `babel`. Otherwise consider to update your `setup (as mentioned  MadyYuvi in his comment).

Comment: I use `\RequirePackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}` `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` solved my problem! Thank you! For others who have the same issue please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw

Comment: @Passe, problems with babel, which in many languages change the meaning of some characters, is well known :-). I edit my answer and add babel package and library to code. Now it should work in your document. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @Zarko Now, I integrated your suggestion in my document. I noticed, that the interruption looks a bit small in comparison to the text. I tried to fix it by myself but without success... Could you mention, witch parameters are responsible for the size and the gap between the two wavy lines??

Comment: @Passe,defined are in `decoration` in part `mark=at position 0.5 with  {\draw[line width=1.6pt, -]  (0pt,4pt) .. controls + (2pt,-2pt) and + (-2pt,2pt) .. (0pt,-4pt);
                        \draw[white, line width=1pt, solid, -]
                            (0pt,4.1pt) .. controls + (2pt,-2pt) and + (-2pt,2pt) .. (0pt,-4.1pt);
                                            }`. To enlarge it accordingly change line widths for example from `1.6pt` and `1pt` to  `2.4pt` and `1.8pt` , from  change coordinates for drawings,  (0,4pt) to  for example `(0,7pt) .