# Connecting normal lines with decorated ones

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, node-connections

I've got a problem, I've tried it a lot and I've investigated about it but I haven't found the answer.

I've got a code like this....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thick, latex-] (0,8) -- (0,1);
  \draw[very thick] decorate [decoration={zigzag}] {(0,1) -- (0,0)};
  \draw[very thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (14,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And I want to do a full `\draw` or `\path` joining the first `\draw` with the second one (the one with decoration) and the third, so the upper line connects with the *zigzaged* one at (0,1), then draw the decorated line and then at (0,0) connect this line with the other.

I would really appreciate the ideas.

Comment: Hi Paco, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your question to make your code into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  and I added a screenshot. It looks a little bit like you're creating an axis- if so, I recommend the `pgfplots` package. Welcome!

Comment: Related (or even duplicate): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18436/draw-the-discontinuity-symbol-with-tikz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ti*k*Z

You can `decorate` only one part of the path.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thick,latex-latex,decoration={zigzag}]
                                               (0,8) -- (0,1) decorate {-- (0,0)} -- (14,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

#### Output

[image: TikZ solution]

Detail:
[image: Tikz solution: detail]

### [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)

As cmhughes already commented, you might be interested in the `pgfplots` package. The following example is taken from the manual.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=center,
    tick align=outside,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    ymin=95, enlargelimits=false
]
    \addplot[
        blue,
        mark=none,
        domain=-4:4,
        samples=20
    ]
    { x*x+x+104 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: pgfplots solution]