# Discontinuity of log axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Using log-scale for bar charts is probably not a good idea due to the lack of a true zero.

However, given skewed data, there doesn't seem to be much alternative ... otherwise smaller values get too compressed for comparison.

Using `xbar` in `pgfplots`, my idea was to use log scale for the *x*-axis, but indicate the zero issue using a discontinuity in the axis.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
 axis x discontinuity=crunch,
 log basis x=2,
 log origin=infty,
 y post scale=0.4,
 legend style={at={(0.5,1.1)},anchor=south},
 legend columns=4,
 ytick={one,two,eight,sixty-four},
 symbolic y coords={one,two,eight,sixty-four},
 bar width=7pt,
 enlarge y limits=0.5 
]

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(1,one)};
\addlegendentry{one}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(2,two)};
\addlegendentry{two}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(8,eight)};
\addlegendentry{eight}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(64,sixty-four)};
\addlegendentry{sixty-four}

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

The output looks fine (with a little further non-MWE tweaking), but I receive two error messages upon build:

### Errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
          \pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x 
l.30 \end{semilogxaxis}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
               \pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x 
l.30 \end{semilogxaxis}
```

I guess this is to do with the lack of a "true origin" to shift the discontinuity from on the axis. However, the output achieves what I want. Hence ...

Can anyone suggest a method to fix the error? Otherwise, how could I suppress such errors?

(I think I would also like to label the x origin with "0" if anyone had suggestions for that.)

Comment: I would say a better alternative would be just using a scatterplot instead of a bar plot...

Comment: In my case, there's no ordering on the secondary axis. Hence there are no Cartesian co-ordinates and, for me, scatter plots have the wrong "semantics". ... put another way, I don't have a 2D plot but a collection of 1D plots that are comparable, but not ordered.

Comment: this is a bug in pgfplots. I will take a note to fix it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a decoration to place the axis discontinuity. The decoration in the example below is adapted from [Draw the discontinuity symbol with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18436/draw-the-discontinuity-symbol-with-tikz).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{discontinuity}{start}{
  \state{start}[width=0.04\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=up from center]
  {}
  \state{up from center}[width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength, next state=big down]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{big down}[next state=center finish]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{center finish}[width=0.5\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance, next state=do nothing]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}
  }
  \state{do nothing}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=do nothing]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
 log basis x=2,
 log origin=infty,
 y=0.5cm,
 legend style={at={(0.5,1.1)},anchor=south},
 legend columns=-1,
 ytick={one,two,eight,sixty-four},
 symbolic y coords={one,two,eight,sixty-four},
 bar width=7pt,
 enlarge y limits=0.5,
 enlarge x limits={0.15},
 separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style=
{decoration={discontinuity, segment length=3mm}, decorate},
]

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(1,one)};
\addlegendentry{one}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(2,two)};
\addlegendentry{two}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(8,eight)};
\addlegendentry{eight}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(64,sixty-four)};
\addlegendentry{sixty-four}

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

In my eyes, a better alternative to a discontinuity symbol on a logarithmic axis (which really doesn't make any sense mathematically) would be to use a scatter plot. To show that the data is essentially one-dimensional, you could use a y grid:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
 log basis x=2,
 log origin=infty,
 y=0.5cm,
 legend style={at={(0.5,1.1)},anchor=south},
 legend columns=-1,
 ytick={one,two,eight,sixty-four},
 symbolic y coords={one,two,eight,sixty-four},
 bar width=7pt,
 enlarge y limits=0.5,
 enlarge x limits={0.15},
 ymajorgrids=true
]

\addplot coordinates {(1,one)};
\addlegendentry{one}

\addplot coordinates {(2,two)};
\addlegendentry{two}

\addplot coordinates {(8,eight)};
\addlegendentry{eight}

\addplot coordinates {(64,sixty-four)};
\addlegendentry{sixty-four}

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! (The y-grid is a nice alternative: it discourages looking for an arbitrary trend across the grid/series. However, in my view, the logarithmic y-grid suffers the exact same problem as for a bar plot, or indeed any plot with 0 in its interval.)